# RxJava, поворот экрана, и сетевой запрос в Android

Tags: android, rxjava, activity-life-cycle, livedata

Начинаю изучать RxJava и интересует вопрос, а именно следующая ситуация, например я делаю сетевой запрос, он занимает несколько секунд, и в этот момент я делаю поворот экрана. Что произойдет с данными? Куда они придут? Получу я их во вновь созданной активити после поворота? Отслеживает ли RxJava жизненный цикл активити как например Livedata? И как правильно тогда обработать результат запроса? Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изучите паттерны, к примеру `MVVM`,`MVP Moxy`.

**Один из примеров реализации `MVVM` к вашему вопросу:**

В`ViewModel` мы создаем `LiveData` или `Subject's` из `RxJava 2`, в `onResume()` `Activity/Fragment` мы подписываемся на `LiveData` или `Subject` которые берем из `ViewModel`, но если решились использовать `Subject's` то не забудьте их отписать, к примеру в `onStop()` `Activity/Fragment`.. Все запросы в сеть с помощью `RxJava` мы делаем внутри `ViewModel`, а когда в `subscribe()` мы получаем данные которые надо передать в `Activity/Fragment` то мы используем `LiveData` или `Subject`. И в `ViewModel` не забудьте отписаться от всех `Observable`, обычно это делают в методе `onCleared()`.

Answer (score 2):

RxJava никак не связана с жизненным циклом компонентов андроид приложений. Она даже сделана изначально для Java, не для андроид. И, например, `AndroidSchedullers.mainThread()` не находится внутри стандартной библиотеки.

С данными может всякое произойти - зависит от того как и что вы с ними делаете. Вы можете как утечку памяти получить, так и данные в пересозданной активити.

Обычно задачу переживания пересоздания активити решают с помощью архитектурных библиотек, в которых результаты запросов приходят в экземпляры специальных классов, не умирающих вместе с активити и передающих в пересозданную активити данные, когда она к этому будет готова. При этом будет не важно как вы получаете данные - через  `rxJava`, в AsyncTask, Thread, Retrofit, OkHttp.

В качестве послених можете посмотреть на `RxPm` или `Moxy`.